# Cotangent bundles to Riemannian manifolds and submanifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $N$ be a Riemannian manifold, and $\widetilde{N}\subset N$ a closed submanifold.  If we look at the total spaces of the tangent bundles, we get that $T\widetilde{N}$ is a submanifold of $TN$.

If we now use the metric to identify $\widetilde{M}=T^*\widetilde{N}$ with $T\widetilde{N}$, and $M=T^*N$ with $TN$, this gives an embedding of $\widetilde{M}$ into $M$.

Both of $\widetilde{M}$ and $M$ are of course symplectic manifolds, with canonical symplectic forms.  Is there a coordinate-free way of seeing that this is a symplectic embedding, i.e. that the canonical symplectic form on $M$ restricts to the canonical symplectic form on $\widetilde{M}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I please call the submanifold $M$ instead of $\tilde N$?

For a smooth manifold $N$, $T^\ast N$ does not just have a canonical symplectic form $\omega$. It also has a canonical $1$-form $\alpha$ such that $d\alpha=\omega$. For $w\in T^\ast N$, the element $\alpha_w\in T^\ast_w(T^\ast N)$ can be defined in a coordinate-free way by giving its value at $v\in T_w(T^\ast N)$:
$$
\langle \alpha_w,v\rangle=\langle w,\pi_\ast v\rangle
$$
where $\pi_\ast :T_w(T^\ast N)\to T_{\pi(w)} N$ is induced by the bundle projection $\pi:T^\ast N\to N$.

In the presence of a Riemannian structure on $N$ this becomes:

For $w\in T N$, the element $\alpha_w\in T^\ast_w(T N)$ is defined by giving its value at $v\in T_w(T N)$:
$$
\langle \alpha_w,v\rangle=w\cdot \pi_\ast v
$$
Here "$\cdot$" means Riemannian inner product, and $\pi:T N\to N$ is the bundle projection.

If the $\alpha $ for $N$ restricts to the $\alpha$ for $M$ then also the $\omega$ restricts to the $\omega$. And surely this is the case; for $w\in TM$ and $v\in T_w(TM)$ the inner product $w\cdot \pi_\ast v$ is the same whether calculated in $M$ or in $N$.